# How to find the number of columns in which records are more than 3?

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

To solve this problem I take names of columns from information_schema.columns and make query which should count number of records in one column. But that subquery returns more than 1 value and I don't know why, because it should return number of rows - one value. Please explain me what I'm doing wrong.

```
SELECT count(COLUMN_NAME)

FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS

WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'users' group by COLUMN_NAME having((select count(COLUMN_NAME) from users where COLUMN_NAME is not null)>3)
```

Columns

```
   name | surname
__________________
    a   | b
    c   | d
    e   | f
    e   | null
```

Function should return 1 (name column have 4 records)

Comment: What do you mean by a column that has more than 3 rows? Tables have rows, not Columns. Also, `select count(COLUMN_NAME) from users)` would count the value of `COLUMN_NAME` from the object `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` against the rows of the table `users`; which makes no sense.

Comment: @Diado Actually I'm using sql server

Comment: @Larnu Some records in columns can be NULL. I need to find number of not null records in column.

Comment: Perhaps this script i wrote on SSC answers the question: [Count non-NULL rows and get definition](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/?p=3733586&post_type=ssc_script&preview_id=3733586)

Comment: Also, SQL Server doesn't have "records", there are columns and rows, and there are values within a specific column in a specific row. A "record" isn't a defined *thing* in SQL.

Comment: You need dynamic SQL here.

Comment: Number of columns of *what*?  Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I've already added example

Comment: @Larnu name and surname are columns name

Comment: Why is the query not simply `SELECT COUNT([name]) - COUNT(surname) FROM dbo.YourTable;`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this solution:

```
DECLARE dsql STRING;
DECLARE qry STRING;
SET qry = (
    SELECT
      STRING_AGG(ARRAY_TO_STRING(["SELECT '", column_name, "' AS ColumnName, " || "COUNT(" || column_name || ") AS RowCount FROM mydataset.", table_name, ' union all'], ''), ' ')
    FROM
      mydataset.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE
      table_name = 'users' );
SET dsql = 'SELECT * FROM ( ' || SUBSTR(qry, 1, LENGTH(qry) - LENGTH(' union all')) || ') WHERE RowCount > 3';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE dsql;
```